# How to overcome "post search" deprecation in Graph API 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I understand that Facebook has deprecated searching for posts in its 2.0 version of Graph API. Also, from what I understand, we can still access posts-search using version 1 and APPS created before 30-april-2014.

My trouble is I have to start this project that lets me do some analytics on certain topics by extracting social media content pertaining to them. So, my first step is to get as many posts as possible regarding this topic. I just started hence I do not have any apps created before 30-April-2014. Also from what I understand, even if I did have apps, I would have needed a lot of valid apps as the Graph API is rate limited. So the only way to get good dataset would have been to keep on extracting posts with different APP ID as soon as the previous APPID hits the rate limit.

Can anyone suggest a feasible option to get this done? Is there a possible way to still get Facebook posts data? Are there vendors who can give me streaming access to data (Like DATASIFT, btw I tried their Facebook API and it's terribly slow. Their Twitter API is magnificent).

Comment: Well there’s the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) – but that’s limited to certain FB partners. (And they removed the list of partners from that page by the looks of it, dunno why.)

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it and it seems its not really well documented as to how to get access. Plus it looks like a pretty long drawn process to become an official facebook partner. There are social media analysis products which manage this, I am just wondering how this may be possible for them? Another question might be, that if I do manage to get access to an app created before 30 April 2014, what are the ways I can use that to counter rate limiting? Can I use same app with different user IDs? Thanks.